# React-Native-Maps <LocalTiles /> is not working

Tags: react-native, qgis, react-native-maps

I am currently working to display  by using React-Native-Maps; these are my steps:

1 by using QGIS, I have generated a folder with XYZ files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUcHI.png)

2 I have uploaded the XYZ files to android emulator under Download:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV1ta.png)

3 in my React-Native code, I use  component and gave the path:

```js
<MapView
  style={styles.map}
  mapType={Platform.OS == "android" ? "none" : "standard"}
>
  <LocalTile
    // The path template of the locally stored tiles. The patterns {x} {y} {z} will be                    replaced at runtime
    // For example, /storage/emulated/0/mytiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
    pathTemplate={`${RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath}/123/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`}
    // The size of provided local tiles (usually 256 or 512).
    tileSize={512}
  />
  // I also tried the UrlTile
  <UrlTile
    urlTemplate={`file://${RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath}/123/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`}
    zIndex={10}
  />
</MapView>
```

I have console.log the pathTemplate, it did direct to "/storage/emulated/0/Download/123/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"

but the page shows nothing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNKAX.png)

can someone help me with this? I am not sure if this is a XYZ file problem or path issue

Thank you

the map will display the XYZ tiles

Answer (score 2):

I was working on something similar, that's the code, that worked for me (both UrlTile and LocalTile are working):

```js
import React from "react";
import MapView, { LocalTile, UrlTile } from "react-native-maps";
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";

const MapScreen = () => {
  const urlTemplate =
    "file://" +
    RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir +
    "/assets/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
  const localTemplate =
    RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + "/assets/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";

  const initialRegion = {
    latitude: 50.0647,
    longitude: 19.945,
    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
    longitudeDelta: 0.01,
  };

  return (
    <MapView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        top: 0,
        position: "absolute",
      }}
      minZoomLevel={16}
      maxZoomLevel={16}
      initialRegion={initialRegion}
    >
      {/* <UrlTile urlTemplate={urlTemplate} zIndex={-1} tileSize={256} /> */}
      <LocalTile pathTemplate={localTemplate} tileSize={256} zIndex={-1} />
    </MapView>
  );
};

export default MapScreen;
```

Just make sure, that your XYZ files are right. I used this tool for making tiles: https://blog.studioblueplanet.net/software/open-street-map-tile-downloader and then stored them in data/data/com.appname/files/assets/tiles